# WHy isn't my Javascript working in django template

Tags: javascript, django, zurb-foundation

Below is the Template code that I am using. I am using foundation as a framework and right now I'm just trying to pull up a range slider. Using the same Static type links, the css works fine, its just the javascript that doesnt seem to work for me. When I trace the file in view source and click on the link of the file, it takes me to the file's code. Wi that, why wouldnt the js code be working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
      {% load staticfiles %}


<link href="{% static "styling/css/normalize.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="{% static "styling/css/foundation.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "styling/css/custom.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">




<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
   <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;">
    <span class="range-slider-handle"></span>
   <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
 <span id="sliderOutput3"></span>
</div>
  </div>




 <script src="{% static "styling/js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static "styling/js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script>
 <script>

   $(document).foundation();

 </script>


  </body>
```

Comment: How about a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem? Maybe copy the relevant sections from the rendered output, as well as the raw template.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your missing the <kbd>></kbd> sign at the end of the foundation script tag:

```
<script src="{% static "styling/js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script
```

Should've been:

```
<script src="{% static "styling/js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script>
```

You should check the resulting html via [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) (or some other validator), this usually helps.

Comment: How I wish that were it, the code actually just didn't copy over well I fixed that on this question but i my code its there

Comment: Did you ran it in the validator ? e.g I see in your code that you open 3 divs but closing only 2, etc.

Did you check that the js files are loaded by the browser ?

It hard to help with only fragments of template/code.

Comment: How would I check if they are loaded in the browser? I did a view source, clicked on the links and they brought me to the JS files that I linked.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools for that. In the network tab, you can see the traffic and responses.

Plus: The html passed the validator ?

Comment: Also, what more would you like me to add to the code? , the div tags are closed, I dont know why it came over so bad when I did the copy paste

Comment: I got errors in the html validator but they were related to this and the chrome network tab is loading the files, could this be a django thing?? Does foundation not work with django?

Comment: No, I've worked with Django and Foundation, Bootstrap, ExtJS, Dojo and many other frameworks.

Do you see errors in the browser's (chrome in your case) console ?

If you can supply a test project I can check the code.